# ～しよう＋としてします。 What is the meaning of this expression?

Tags: syntax

I always see this sentence being used. Like **忘れようとしてします** or **毎日勉強しようとしてする**
I'm just wondering what is the difference if I use **忘れる** or **勉強する** instead. Whenever I watch anime or JDrama I always here this pattern. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Are you sure about the する on the end?

Comment: Yup. There's no way I misheard this because I always hear this everytime.

Comment: Ending with して**い**ます would make a lot better sense than what you're hearing...

Comment: Yes , it could also be in that form since the present form of 　する is しています. What I'm a looking for is the meaning of this expression / sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between, for example, 勉強しようとする and 勉強する is simply the difference between "to try to study/to be about to study/to get down to studying" (depending on the context) and "to study."

As for the construction しようとしてする, I found a couple of examples on Twitter: "おやすみってツイートしようとしてする前に寝てた" and "恋はしようとしてするもんじゃない恋は落ちるもの." However, in these, しようとしてする cannot be taken as a single lexical unit. The first one has a break between the しよう and the する ("I **was about to** (しようとして) tweet goodnight, but fell asleep before **doing so** (する)." And in the second one, するもの means that love is "a thing to do" (するもの) that cannot be a "try to/be about to/get down to doing" (しようとして) "thing to do." I.e., the しようとして is like an adjective that describes (or, in the tweeter's mind, shouldn't be allowed to describe) the するもの. In other words, there's no half-assing about with love - you fall in or you don't.